# Evulating $\int_I f$ by using Darboux Sum convergence Criterion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, integration

I tried to solve the question. But, there may be some mistakes. I want to learn this properly. If there exist any notation mistake, typo, a general mistake in solution way or else, please correct this.

Thank you:)

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is a repeat of a previous question. I recommend offering a bounty on the old one. :)

Comment: Really? I forgot the existence of the question. Sorry, I Will see it. @EricAuld

Comment: No No , I never asked any question related to Darboux Sum convergence Criterion @EricAuld

Comment: My apologies. ----

Comment: Doesnt matter:) @EricAuld

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The volume of $J$ should be $\frac{1}{n^2}$. So, you have the sum $$\frac{1}{n^5}\sum_{k,l=1}^nk^2l=\frac{1}{n^5}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\sum_{l=1}^nl=\frac{1}{n^5}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\frac{n(n+1)}{2},$$ which converges to $\frac{1}{6}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Ohh, okay thank you:))